# ActiveMQ Message sending on a topic

Tags: activemq-classic

Using ActiveMQ v 5.8

I am using javax.jms.MessageProducer.send() to send messages from my producer to ActiveMQ.

I want to know whether this sending is synchronous or asynchronous? And what will be the behavior if I make "useAsyncSend" flag to true ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ sends message in async mode by default in several cases. It is only in cases where the JMS specification required the use of sync sending that we default to sync sending. The cases that we are forced to send in sync mode are when persistent messages are being sent outside of a transaction.

If you are not using transactions and are sending persistent messages, then each send is synch and blocks until the broker has sent back an acknowledgement to the producer that the message has been safely persisted to disk. This ack provides that guarantee that the message will not be lost but it also costs a huge latency penalty since the client is blocked.

See the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/async-sends.html) on this at the ActiveMQ s.

Comment: I am already using non-persistent messages and not using transactions.      In this case the send call is blocking or not ? If Yes, than at what level, will it be waiting for broker to send acknowledgement or only waiting till messages gets into socketBuffer ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer any more clearly, did you read the docs?  The non-persistent messages are sent async unless you configure things otherwise.  Async sends mean that once the bytes are written to the socket we return and make no promise that it will reach the broker.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I understood that. I just wanted to know that "Is there any difference in sending non-persistence messages with or without async flag ? "

Comment: No, for message that are already sent out async, the async send flag won't make them go out even more async.

Answer (score 0):

yes, by default a send() is synchronous (for persistent queue/topic, async otherwise) and will block until an ACK has been received...

with `useAsyncSend=true` will not block...

per http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html

> Async Sends adds a massive performance boost; but means that the send() method will return immediately whether the message has been sent or not which could lead to message loss.

Comment: Even If I send non-persistence messages to a topic, the sending will be synchronous? Only case when sending is asynchronous when I use **useAsyncSend=true**

Comment: by default, persistence in enabled and the send() is synchronous...to change this, you can either set to non-persistent or set the useAsyncSend=true

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As you have specified that if I want asynchronous message sending either (i) I should use non-persistence messaging or (ii) I can set useAsyncSend to true. Just curious to understand the difference between both case ?

Comment: Does it block producer or consumer?